# Legend ArcGIS Javascript does not recognize Legend from ArcGIS for server 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend

I have created maps in ArcGIS for desktop and published them to ArcGIS for server 10.2.2. Because of performance issues I have created a group layer of the same map with different levels of details. They all have the exact same symbology. I add the group layer in my script as one layer. I am attempting to create a legend with it but I am not succeeding. I do get a box with the note "No Legend". This indicates to me it does not recognize my legend from my ArcGIS Server. Could anybody help me?

This question is a follow up of a previous question of me that seems to be fully answered since I am getting the legend box: [Add a legend in an ArcGIS Javascript API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137599/add-a-legend-in-an-arcgis-javascript-api)

```
 <script>
        var map;
        var wmsLayer;
        var URL;
        var legend;
        require(["dojo/query", "esri/map", "esri/layers/WMSLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (query, Map, WMSLayer, Legend, esriConfig) {

          esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/proxy_gcx.php";

          map = new Map("map", {
              basemap: "topo",
              center: [5.5, 52.485],
              minZoom: 8,
              maxZoom: 13,
              zoom: 8,
              slider: true
          });

          wmsLayer = new WMSLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/services/P_00_15/P_00_15/MapServer/WMSServer", {
              format: "png",
              visibleLayers: ["31", "30", "29", "28"]
          });

          map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
          map.on("layer-add", function (results) {
              //add the legend
              legend = new Legend({
                  map: map,
                  layerInfos: [{
                      layer: results,
                      title: "P_00_2013"
                  }]
              }, "legendDiv");
              legend.startup();

          });

      });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="legendDiv"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might work this way: at layerInfos you should add as layer your wmsLayer and not the 'results':

```
layerInfos: [{
    layer: wmsLayer,
    title: "P_00_2013"
}]
```